# Python Regex: how to not select whitespace before last string?

Tags: python, regex, text

I am (a newbie,) struggling with separating a database in columns with regex.findall().

I want to separate these Dutch street names into name and number.

```
Roemer Visscherstraat 15
Vondelstraat 102-huis
```

For the number I use

```
 \S*$
```

Which works just fine. For the street name I use

```
^\S.+[^\S$]
```

Or: use everything but the last element, which may be a number or a combination of a number and something else.

Problem is: Python then also keeps the last whitespace after the last name, so I get:

'Roemer Visscherstraat '

Any way I can stop this from happening?

Also, Findall returns a list consisting of the bit of database I wanted, and an empty string. How does this happen and can i prevent it somehow?

Thanks so much in advance for you help.

Comment: Hold on, you are separating a database manually? Don't do that.

Comment: `[^\S$]` is equivalent to `[^\S]`, which is equivalent to `\s`, because `\S` already includes `$`.

Answer (score 0):

You can `rstrip()` the name to remove any spaces at the end of it:

```
>>>'Roemer Visscherstraat '.rstrip()
'Roemer Visscherstraat'
```

But if the input is similar to the one you posted, you can simply use `split()` instead of regex, for example:

```
st = 'Roemer Visscherstraat 15'
data = st.split()
num = st[-1]
name = ' '.join(st[:-1])
print 'Name: {}, Number: {}'.format(name, num)
```

output:

```
Name: Roemer Visscherstraat, Number: 15
```

Answer (score 0):

```
([^\d]*)\s+(\d.*)
```

In this regex the first group captures everything before a space and a number and the 2nd group gives the desired number 
my assumption is that number would begin with a digit and the name would not have a digit in it 
take a look at https://regex101.com/r/eW0UP2/1

> Roemer Visscherstraat 15

```
Full match  0-24    `Roemer Visscherstraat 15`
Group 1.    0-21    `Roemer Visscherstraat`
Group 2.    22-24   `15`
```

> Vondelstraat 102-huis

```
Full match  24-46   `Vondelstraat 102-huis`
Group 1.    24-37   `Vondelstraat`
Group 2.    38-46   `102-huis`
```

Comment: The "number" may not be only digits, as you can see from OP.

Answer (score 0):

For the number you should use the following:

```
\S+$
```

Using a `+` instead of a `*` will ensure that you have at least one character in the match.

For the street name you can use the following:

```
^.+(?=\s\S+$)
```

What this does is selects text up until the number.

**However**, what you may consider doing is using one regex match with capture groups instead. The following would work:

```
^(.+(?=\s\S+$))\s(\S+$)
```

In this case, the first capture group gives you the street name, and the second gives you the number.